# Two categorical variables with many levels, dependent samples

Tags: regression, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, frequentist, mcnemar-test

I have data from many participants, who each answered the same question about each of several stimuli, assigning each stimulus to a category (with replacement). This would be an example of said data structure:

```r
library(tidyverse)

id <- 1:5
stimulus <- c("A", "B", "C")

dat <- tidyr::expand_grid(id, stimulus) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    response = sample(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"),
      size = n(),
      replace = TRUE
    )
  )

dat
```

For those more used to an SPSS-like, one participant per row structure:

```r
dat_wide <- dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = stimulus,
    values_from = response
  )
```

`dat_wide` then returns:

```r
     id A     B     C    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 cat1  cat3  cat4 
2     2 cat4  cat4  cat3 
3     3 cat1  cat3  cat3 
4     4 cat3  cat2  cat1 
5     5 cat2  cat2  cat2
```

I'd like to perform inference on whether the different stimuli are assigned to different categories, preferably (for now) in a frequentist framework. I see two problems:

1. Each variable (stimulus and response) has much more than two levels. This makes pairwise comparisons not scale well, but I could live with that.
2. Responses are not independent, since every participant responds to each stimulus. Thus I would be hesitant to perform a regular chi-square test. But afaik McNemar won't work with so many levels of the variables.

A third issue: technically, the categories could be reasonably considered ordinal. However, I would prefer not to force an ordering, for substantive reasons (e.g., ordered logit or probit models don't make sense to me for these categories).

My questions:

- What would you do in this situation?
- Would treating the categories as ordinal make this substantially easier? How?

Comment: Did every respondent rate every stimulus? Or is there some missing data?

Comment: @DavidSmith Yes, they did. No missing data.

Comment: I'm puzzled. I don't know what question you want to answer. You could make a 5 x 5 x 5 contingency table with 125 cells. The table might have a number of patterns of interest to test. Which ones were of interest prior to conducting the experiment?

Comment: @DavidSmith, I'm aware that I'm not too clear on the inferences I'd like to make -- it's part of why I'm asking for help. But I don't think a subjects x stimuli x responses table would make sense... I have close to 100 participants. 
If the response was somehow continuous, I'd be interested in in the effect of "stimulus" on response, like so: lmer(response ~ stimulus); or lmer(response ~ stimulus + (stimulus | id) to account for multiple measurements per participant. Almost equivalently, a repetead measures ANOVA. Does this help at all?

Comment: The table would be for response1 by response2 by response3. Each subject would be in exactly one cell of the table.  The table summarizes all the responses of the participants. Since the table has 125 cells and you have 100 subjects then, if there are meaningful patterns, there will be a lot of empty cells. You might start with a description of the cells where respondents agree in large numbers.

Comment: I still don't understand where the 125 cells come from. Why 5 x 5 x 5?

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you gave. I think it should be 4 x 4 x 4, since there are four possible values that each respondent can give to each stimulus, for a total of 64 cells.